# phpmyadmin suddenly returns parse error on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (Trusty Tahr)

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-14.04

On a recent install of a Ubuntu server (Apache2 + Ispconfig + FastCgi & php-fpm), I cannot access anymore to phpmyadmin, which returns following errors :

- *Warning: Unexpected character in input: '⌉' (ASCII=2) state=0 in /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5 on line 6194*
- *Parse error: in /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5 on line 6194*

No more information in the logs. Apache2 error.log says exactly the same whenever I try to access.
Everything else is working fine.

The most recent changes I made to the machine were an `apt-get upgrade` with the following packets :

```
libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 linux-libc-dev python3-distupgrade
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core x11proto-core-dev xtrans-dev
```

Your help is really welcome, thank you !